# Tell webpack to explicitly include a folder

Tags: node.js, webpack, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I'm using serverless.com to deploy my node js app to AWS.

I need to include the dir `./src/email-templates/**` which includes .ejs and .scss files that are used by the email-templates module.

For example:

```
import * as EmailTemplate from 'email-templates';
template = EmailTemplate.EmailTemplate('./email-templates/default');
```

Here's what my webpack looks like:

```
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires */
const path = require('path');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
const slsw = require('serverless-webpack');
const ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin = require('fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin');

const isLocal = slsw.lib.webpack.isLocal;

module.exports = {
  mode: isLocal ? 'development' : 'production',
  entry: slsw.lib.entries,
  externals: [nodeExternals(), "aws-sdk"],
  devtool: 'source-map',
  resolve: {
    extensions: [ '.js', '.jsx', '.json', '.ts', '.tsx' ]
  },
  output: {
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
    path: path.join(__dirname, '.webpack'),
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  target: 'node',
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.ejs$/, loader: 'ejs-loader?variable=data' },
      {
        // Include ts, tsx, js, and jsx files.
        test: /\.(ts|js)x?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'cache-loader',
            options: {
              cacheDirectory: path.resolve('.webpackCache')
            }
          },
          'babel-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: [
          // Creates `style` nodes from JS strings
          'style-loader',
          // Translates CSS into CommonJS
          'css-loader',
          // Compiles Sass to CSS
          'sass-loader',
        ],
      },
    ]
  },
  plugins: [new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin()]
};
```

When I run `sls deploy --stage=dev` to deploy the EmailTemplates instance can't find that folder. Here's the error:

```
Failed to render email { [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat './email-templates/notification']
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'stat',
  path: './email-templates/notification' }
```

Hence it looks like webpack is not packaging it.

Is there anyway to explicitly tell webpack to include a folder?

Comment: i'm not really familiar with webpack, but shouldn't you be using [file-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/) to include files/directories?

Comment: You want webpack to process ejs and sass files which are not referenced from entry -- right? Why wont u add separate entry for them then?

Comment: I've managed to include them using file-loader and explicitly stating `const defaultHtml = require('../email-templates/default/html.ejs');`. This works, but it's not great that I have to include this line for every single ejs and scss file I have. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Have you already looked at [`CopyWebpackPlugin`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/copy-webpack-plugin/)?

Comment: You could try to use glob patterns. Try a module like `webpack-glob-entry` or anything similar.

Answer (score 1):

One of the comments mentioned [`CopyWebpackPlugin`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/copy-webpack-plugin), which I think is what you're looking for as the most 'canonical webpack' way to:

> Cop[y] individual files or entire directories, which already exist, to the build directory.

After install:

`npm install copy-webpack-plugin --save-dev`

Require it in your `webpack` config file:

`const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin')`

And update the `plugins` property in the config:

```
  plugins: [
    new CopyPlugin({
      patterns: [
        // ALL .scss files emitted under '<top-level-dist>/email-templates', maintaining sub-folder structure
        {
          from: 'src/email-templates/**/*.scss',
          to: './email-templates',
        },
        // ALL .ejs files copied under '<top-level-dist>/email-templates', maintaining sub-folder structure
        {
          from: 'src/email-templates/**/*.ejs',
          to: './email-templates',
        },
      ],
    }),
    new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin()
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Webpack just build referenced files with require(...) if your file (.ejs in your case) is not required in any .js file, it will not be include.

Also webpack is almost always to transpile or build several .js files into one minified or compresed javascript file. A ejs file is required in a static way, so no minified or compresed is required.

As comments said you, add the ejs files after webpack result as a folder